# Accidentlly deleted files in xcode 6 - how to undo

Tags: xcode

I pressed "delete" in the keyboard, thinking it would delete code, but instead I saw that it deleted files!

I don't know what files it deleted, and I can't checkout everything because I didn't commit yet

How do I know what files it deleted and how do I undo this?

Answer (score 0):

You use the powers of backup. There should be a very recent version in your git repository, and there should be a version less than an hour old in your Time Machine backup.

If there is neither present, then you just learned a lesson.

But actually, the deleted file is either where it always was and can be added back to the project, or it is in the trash and can be moved from there to where it should be.

Comment: And if it's a source code file, a build should come up with a error. Header files will only complain if really moved to the trash, and resources like images are more likely to get silently ignored...